# reCaptcha without using PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a backoffice of a webshop provider. They do not allow adding PHP into their template editor. Does anyone know of a way to add/operate [**Google reCaptcha**](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) without PHP?

Comment: reCaptcha is used when submitting a form. How do you acess the form values on the server? This is the place where you validate your reCaptcha.

Comment: I access the value of the form via a template editor. In this template editor I edit a snippet that has my form in it. This snippet does not accept PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You must use some server-side language on the backend to validate the captcha, as @elementzero23 correctly noted.

It doesn't have to be PHP specifically, it could be .NET, node.js, Python and what not. But if you're only allowed to upload html/css/js files on your server then not, you won't be able to use any CAPTCHA protection at all.

Comment: yes, I am only aloud to upload html/css/js files :(

Comment: or any captcha for that matter

Comment: It it possible to have the form on another server with a reCaptcha, and load the form in my website in an iframe?

Comment: It's possible, yes. But maybe then host all of your site on that another sever?